# How to add 2 expressions in mule xpath?

Tags: mule

I want to make two checks. I am doing it like below

```
#[xpath:/ns0:UpdateUserResponse/ns0:ErrorReport/ns0:ErrorCode/text() = '200' & 
xpath:/ns0:UpdateUserResponse/ns0:ErrorReport/ns0:ErrorDescription/text() = 'Invalid Login']
```

It trows error like,

Unexpected '& xpath:/ns0:UpdateUserResponse/ns0:ErrorReport/ns0:ErrorDescription/text() = 'Invalid Login'' (org.jaxen.saxpath.XPathSyntaxException)
  org.jaxen.saxpath.base.XPathReader:1084 (null)

Please tell me how to add two checks in one expression ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :-

```
#[xpath:/ns0:UpdateUserResponse/ns0:ErrorReport/ns0:ErrorCode/text() = '200' and
xpath:/ns0:UpdateUserResponse/ns0:ErrorReport/ns0:ErrorDescription/text() = 'Invalid Login']
```

**UPDATE :-**
You need to encode `&` by using `&amp;` ...
Use `&amp;&amp;` instead of `&&` in the expression
So your expression will be :-

```
#[xpath:/ns0:UpdateUserResponse/ns0:ErrorReport/ns0:ErrorCode/text() = '200' &amp;&amp;
    xpath:/ns0:UpdateUserResponse/ns0:ErrorReport/ns0:ErrorDescription/text() = 'Invalid Login']
```